# SQL: And / or matches with a many-to-many join

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I'm a SQL novice, trying to understand how to do a slightly complicated query. Working in a Rails 3 app, I have a many-to-many relationship between Photos and Terms. The setup is pretty vanilla:

```
photos: id

terms: id

photos_terms: photo_id | term_id
```

What I'd like to be able to do is find AND and OR matches among any arbitrary group of terms. So for instance, in pseudo SQL:

```
Select Photos where Term ID in (1 or 2) and (3 or 4 or 5) and (6).
```

How can you write a query like that? For reference, I'm using PostgreSQL.

---

*Update* In response to Rubens answer, here's a bit more info that may help explain the grouping, though I wasn't sure if it was relevant before:

There is another model, Taxonomy, so `taxonomies` table. Each term belongs to a Taxonomy, and a Taxonomy can be either inclusive (meaning it is possible for multiple terms from that taxonomy to apply) or exclusive (meaning terms in that taxonomy are mutually exclusive, only one could apply).

The table relationship is like this:

```
terms: id | taxonomy_id

taxonomy: id | inclusive(boolean)
```

The grouping would be terms from different taxonomies, you always want an AND match for each grouping. You want an AND match among terms from an inclusive Taxonomy, and you want an OR match among terms from an exclusive taxonomy.

To give another pseudo-code example, if we had the following:

```
Taxonomy: Color (inclusive = true)
Terms: Red, Blue, Green

Taxonomy: Location (inclusive = false)
Terms: NY, NJ, PA, MD
```

I might want to query like this:

```
Photos where terms in (red and blue) and (NY or NJ).
```

Does that make sense? FWIW the terms are just like highly structured tags.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. You want to select fotos that have at least one term in each of the three ranges?

Comment: @wildplasser yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM photos p
WHERE 1=1
AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM photos_term pt
    WHERE pt.photo_id = p.id AND term_id IN (1,2)
    )
AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM photos_term pt
    WHERE pt.photo_id = p.id AND term_id IN (3,4,5)
    )
AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM photos_term pt
    WHERE pt.photo_id = p.id AND term_id IN (6)
    )
    ;
```

Comment: What is the difference between your approach `and exists` and michael krelins suggestion of `having bool_or` ?

Comment: IMHO they are equivalent (but I never used bool_or() in my entire life). If you would give the table definitions, we could check if the resulting query plans differ. The optimiser has some nice tricks for both aggregate functions and EXISTS predicate subqueries.

Comment: SQL noob here... what do you mean "give the table definitions"?

Comment: Also, one other question, I may need to have compatibility with SQLite as well, do you know of any issues with this for SQLite?

Comment: I don't know about bool_or(), but EXISTS has been around since the beginning, and should be available on every platform. BTW: your update ("taxonomy") is very confusing. The inclusive = {false,true} part is not understandable by SQL people, at least not by me.

Comment: No worries, that part isn't really relevant to the problem of searching photos, only used for organizing the terms and for controlling the UI, so that's why I didn't include it at first. I was able to adapt this query to work in my app, so thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like

```
SELECT photo_id FROM photos JOIN photos_terms ON (photos.id = photo_id)
WHERE term_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY photo_id
HAVING
 bool_or(term_id IN (1,2))
 AND bool_or(term_id IN (3,4,5))
 AND bool_or(term_id = 6)
```

(where condition is optional, but may speed things up).